# Angular 2 error referencing service proxy- asd:18 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token < SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I apologies for asking this silly question. I am new to Angular 2 and having some issues with the API that my app has consumed. The consumed Web API sits on the following folder structure

```
- src
  - app
    - Registration
      - dashboard.component.html
      - dashboard.component.ts
  - Shared
   - service-proxies
     - service.proxies.ts
     - service-proxy.module.ts
```

The code inside the proxies work correctly as I have moved both of those file inside the app folder and everything works fine. I am getting the following error if the files are inside the Shared directory

```
Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:51860/src/app/registration/dashboard.component.js:14:25)
    at eval (http://localhost:51860/src/app/registration/dashboard.component.js:53:4)
    at eval (http://localhost:51860/src/app/registration/dashboard.component.js:54:3)
Evaluating http://localhost:51860/src/Shared/service-proxies/service-proxies
Evaluating http://localhost:51860/src/app/registration/dashboard.component.js
Evaluating http://localhost:51860/src/app/app.module.js
Evaluating http://localhost:51860/src/main.js
Error loading http://localhost:51860/src/main.js
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:51860/src/app/registration/dashboard.component.js:14:25)
    at eval (http://localhost:51860/src/app/registration/dashboard.component.js:53:4)
    at eval (http://localhost:51860/src/app/registration/dashboard.component.js:54:3)
Evaluating http://localhost:51860/src/Shared/service-proxies/service-proxies
Evaluating http://localhost:51860/src/app/registration/dashboard.component.js
Evaluating http://localhost:51860/src/app/app.module.js
Evaluating http://localhost:51860/src/main.js
Error loading http://localhost:51860/src/main.js
```

The line that is it throwing the error is line 14. Here is the output for my dashboard.component.js

error is thrown on the following line

```
var service_proxies_1 = require("../../Shared/service-proxies/service-proxies");
```

Below is the full output of my file from the browser.

```
    (function(System, SystemJS) {(function(require, exports, module, __filename, __dirname, global, GLOBAL) {"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};
var core_1 = require("@angular/core");
var router_1 = require("@angular/router");
var hero_service_1 = require("../hero.service");
var service_proxies_1 = require("../../Shared/service-proxies/service-proxies");
var DashboardComponent = (function () {
    function DashboardComponent(injector, _storeServiceProxy, heroService, route, router) {
        this._storeServiceProxy = _storeServiceProxy;
        this.heroService = heroService;
        this.route = route;
        this.router = router;
        this.heroes = [];
        this.var1 = route.snapshot.params['id'];
        console.log(this.var1);
    }
    DashboardComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.heroService.getHeroes()
            .then(function (heroes) { return _this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5); });
        this.var2 = this.var1;
        console.log(this.var2);
        this._storeServiceProxy.getStoresByShortCode("")
            .subscribe(function (result) {
            var test = result.isActive;
            var testTwo = result.isActive;
        });
    };
    return DashboardComponent;
}());
DashboardComponent = __decorate([
    core_1.Component({
        selector: 'my-dashboard, ngbd-accordion-static',
        templateUrl: "app/registration/dashboard.component.html",
        styleUrls: ["app/registration/dashboard.component.css"]
    }),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [core_1.Injector,
        service_proxies_1.StoreServiceProxy,
        hero_service_1.HeroService,
        router_1.ActivatedRoute,
        router_1.Router])
], DashboardComponent);
exports.DashboardComponent = DashboardComponent;
//# sourceMappingURL=dashboard.component.js.map
}).apply(__cjsWrapper.exports, __cjsWrapper.args);
})(System, System);
```

Can some one please let me know what I am doing wrong. Keen in mind that if i change the location of the file to app folder everything works fine. Please help

EDIT

Here is the dahsboard.component.ts file

```
    import { Component, Injector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';


import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { StoreServiceProxy } from '../../Shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-dashboard, ngbd-accordion-static',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    private var1: string;
    private var2: string;
    heroes: Hero[] = [];

    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private _storeServiceProxy: StoreServiceProxy,
        private heroService: HeroService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ) { 
        this.var1 = route.snapshot.params['id'];
        console.log(this.var1);

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes()
            .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));

        this.var2 = this.var1;
        console.log(this.var2);

        this._storeServiceProxy.getStoresByShortCode("")
            .subscribe(result => {
                var test = result.isActive;
                var testTwo = result.isActive;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: it will be a good help in determining the issue if you paste the ts file instead of js files for angular. and i you can post snippets of code that too will help

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the error is that referred file is not available. Due to unavailable file index.html content is getting loaded that has < as first character.
To fix it you have to identify at what path your file is available.

To start with based on folder structure that you shared, change

```
import { StoreServiceProxy } from '../../Shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
```

to

```
import { StoreServiceProxy } from '../../Shared/service-proxies/service.proxies';
```

or

```
import { StoreServiceProxy } from '../../Shared/service-proxies/service-proxy.module';
```